# What is the process of solving an equation with the square and the 4th power of an unknown?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

What is the process of solving an equation with the square and the 4th power of an unknown, for example $x^4 - 6x^2 - 27 = 0$?

**Comment**: It's not like I'm just waiting for the answer. I'm asking for the whole method in order to properly learn how to go about the problem.

Comment: sorry do you need  negative numbers?

Comment: I believe so, yes sir.

Comment: please try to do the work on your part before asking a question. you did not show any effort to solve the problem on your part. you are randomly asking for solution.

Comment: It's not like I'm just waiting for the answer. I'm asking for the whole method in order to properly learn how to go about the problem. I don't type it out because I don't have the time to learn LaTeX nor display my entire thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quadratic in terms of $x^2$.  I know solutions have already been posted, but this is the way I like to solve these problems:

$$x^4 -6x^2-27 = (x^2 - 9)(x^2+3)$$

If we are solving: $(x^2 - 9)(x^2+3)=0$, this gives us two equations:
$$x^2-9 = 0 \qquad \text{or} \qquad x^2+3 = 0$$
The one on the left yields:
$$x^2 = 9 \implies x = \pm 3$$
The one on the right yields:(where $i$ is the imaginary unit)
$$x^2 = -3 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{3}i$$

These are the four roots promised us by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.  And, as expected, the complex roots came in conjugate pairs.

Answer (score 5):

substitute $x^2=t$ then $$t^2-6t-27=0$$ this is a quadratic equation in $t$. find the values of $x$ further by substitution.

Answer (score 2):

let us denote $x^2=y$

then we have  $y^2-6y-27=0$  from there $y_1=9$,$y_2=-3$,we dont need negative ones  so we get

$x^2=9$   which means

that $x_1=3$ and

$x_2=-3$

in case of negative number then  $x^2=-3$  we get that $x=i\sqrt{3}$ and   $x=-\sqrt{3}i$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: Eh... you could need negative ones depending on the class.  But, if you're working in the real number system, you can discard negative $y$'s.

Comment: yes but he should mention it,i assume that it is  school  problem,sorry for this

Answer (score 2):

$x^4-6x^2-27=0$
$\implies x^4-9x^2+3x^2-27=0$
$\implies x^2(x^2-9)+3(x^2-9)=0$
$\implies (x^2-9)(x^2+3)=0$
So, $x=+3,-3,\sqrt3i,-\sqrt3i$